# infinite loop with react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have tiredlessly tried everything i can find on stack for this issue and am getting no where. We are using react/typescript. redux, and saga. I have a list of categories to bring back for nav list and using useEffect to dispatch the action to redux store.
our tsx.file:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const categories = useSelector((state) => state?.categories?.payload);
  const loadCategories = () => {
    dispatch(getCategories(categories));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   loadCategories();
  }, []);
 
    {categories?.map((x, index) => (
      <Link href={"/store/" + `${x.name}` + "/s"}>
        <a
          type="button"
          id={`${x.name}`}
          title={`${x.name}`}
          className={"xl:px-3 px-2 py-[1.15rem] font-normal"}>
          {x.name}
        </a>
      </Link>
    ))}
```

Network traffic just shows hundreds of requests going out to the category endpoint -- stumped!

still stuck so adding our redux/saga files
actions:

```js
import {GET_CATEGORIES} from './actionTypes'

export const getCategories = (categories: any) => {
    return {
        type: GET_CATEGORIES,
        payload: categories,
    }
}
```

reducer:

```js
import {GET_CATEGORIES} from './actionTypes'

const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_CATEGORIES:
            state = {
                ...state,
                payload: action.payload,
            }
            break
        default:
            state = {...state}
            break
    }
    return state
}
export default reducer
```

saga:

```js
let categoriesApiService = container.resolve(CategoriesApiService)

const categoryApi = async () => {
    return firstValueFrom(
        categoriesApiService.GetCategoryTree({
            path: {version: '1'},
            query: {},
        })
    )
}

function* getCategoriesTree() {
    try {
        let categoryTreeDTO: CategoryTreeDTO = yield call(categoryApi)
        yield put(getCategories(categoryTreeDTO))
    } catch (error: any) {
        yield put(apiError(error?.response?.data?.message))
    }
}

export function* watchGetCategories() {
    yield takeEvery(GET_CATEGORIES, getCategoriesTree)
}

function* categorySaga() {
    yield all([fork(watchGetCategories)])
}

export default categorySaga
```

Comment: My first guess would be the the whole component is getting constantly unmounted/mounted by one of the ancestor components. Hard to tell without seeing more code.

Comment: It is a global header component.

Comment: Have you tried your browser's dev tools to look at the call stack that leads up to the http request going out? It's probably related to whatever happens inside `getCategories`. The useEffect should only fire once on mount. I don't really know saga, but it looks a bit strange that you're selecting something from the redux store and then pass it back to an action creator (but maybe saga works like that). With the thunk middleware there would be a `getState` function you can call inside the action creator, if the actions needs to look at state.

Comment: Thanks @timotgl going to look there cause i do think it's something in the saga file too

Comment: When debugging infinite loops it can be helpful to add a counter variable to the code (as in, stop sending out requests if the counter reaches > 10) so your browser doesn't go bonkers.

Comment: did get me anywhere but i'm also not an expert in redux. added more code to the questions

Comment: I'm not sure if in `getCategoriesTree` this is correct: `yield put(getCategories(categoryTreeDTO));` Doesn't that cause  an infinitive loop? You dispatch getCategories, `watchGetCategories` picks `GET_CATEGORIES` action and passes them to `getCategoriesTree` for handling. There you again dispatch the `getCategories` action and the round trip starts again? A sidenote: in your reducer, you should not change the state like `state = { ...state };` when you do not handle the action, but just return the old state unchanged. Otherwise redux might assume your state has changed.

Comment: sounds like that is the case not sure how to correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same action to start the saga & to store the fetched data:

component: `dispatch(getCategories(categories))`
saga: `yield put(getCategories(categoryTreeDTO))`

so every time data are fetched the saga is triggered again.

What you want to do is to have different action for storing the fetched data, e.g.:

```js
yield put(getCategoriesSuccess(categoryTreeDTO))
```

(also update your action type in reducer)

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! got it resolved by following your answer :)